# Delete documents with dates older than x in collection from a set of documents in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like this in firebase

/customers/id_x..xx/history/0..n

Under customers I have several documents, under each document I have a collection called history which contains a lot of documents with historical information. The historical document has a timestamp.

What I want to do is to go thru this once a month and delete all documents under the history with a date less than or equal to the run date on all customer documents.

I will create a function in firebase that executes once a month using (node js)

Somehow I guess i need to read all the documents in the root of customers but this could end up as a lengthy progress i suspect because there are a lot of documents.

Any hints pointers would be greatfully appreciated.

Sample data

```
    /customers/2exKxNpe5RRFHRpD3zOrkIlEzel2/usage_history/0Yv0ZASnfxRFnu92JwQx
cardName: "Complaint"
user: "Tennant"
time: April 12, 2021 at 1:18:37 PM UTC+2
comment: "No heat in my appartment"
```

Comment: Please add some example data for the user document and the history documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete outdated history across all users, you'll want to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). This allows you to query the `history` collections across all users in one go.

Aside from that, the code would be quite simple, starting with a query on the `time` field:

```
const now = Date.now();
const lastMonth = now - 30*24*60*60*1000;
const historiesRef = db.collectionGroup('history');
const expiredDocsSnapshot = await historiesRef.where('time', '<', lastMonth).get();
```

And then you loop over the results, deleting them one-by-one or in batches.

You may want to put a `limit` on the query to reduce the number of documents you process in one go, although if that is needed you could also increase how frequently you run the cleanup process.